# How to keep kendo grid header text to the top?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-grid

I am using kendo data grid where i have small issue with header text, Some of the header label has long text becuase of that header text does not look good because of headerAttributes i am using breaks line and making header larger so small text are not aligned properly. Is there a way to place all header to the top so it will look consistent ?

gridConfig.js

```
columns : [

                {
                    field : '',
                    title : 'Action',
                    width: '80px'
                    },


                }, {
                    field : 'riskAssessmentChallengeKey',
                    title : 'Challenge ID',
                    width: '100px',
                    headerAttributes: {
                        style: 'height: auto; white-space: normal'
                    }

                },
                 {
                  field : 'createWorkerText',
                  title : 'Created By',
                  width: '120px',
                  headerAttributes: {
                      style: 'height: auto; white-space: normal'
                                }

              },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some variation of `display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; text-align: center`

or perhaps `display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-pack: center; -webkit-box-align: top;`

I would also probably do this in a CSS fie and add a class in your `headerAtrributes`

`"class": "mygrid-header-cell",`

Then you can put the css in a css file where it belongs.

**EDIT** Note you could also do CSS like this:

```
headerAttributes: { "class": "mygrid-header-cell"}
```

AND CSS

```
.k-grid-header .mygrid-header-cell {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell; vertical-align: top;
}
.k-grid-header .wrap-header {
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What is the second part of css .k-grid-header .wrap-header ? Do i need to use that with my class ?

Comment: That is in case you want the text to wrap, simply add that class to the header element (`.wrap-header`) the other k- class is built into the kendo.  Using those you can make the CSS specific.  Notice the width is NOT specified here and thus it wraps on the width it gets from elsewhere/by default.  Wraps the long lines.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it make sense.Great

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and I do something like this:

```
 .k-grid-header th.k-header {
    vertical-align:top;
  }

  .k-grid-header th.k-header > .k-link {
    max-height: 65px;
    white-space: normal;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    text-align: center;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;

}
```

this is some code that I use (see example): 
http://dojo.telerik.com/OPICO

Shrink and resize the output window to see the effect of this.